# Nginx try_files $uri parameter in subdirectory

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
app/main/index.php
```

```
app/main/catalog.php
```

```
app/main/login.php
```

I want to access files in `app/main directory` with `localhost/admin/{file_name}`

`localhost/admin/index.php` should use `app/main/index.php`, `localhost/admin/catalog.php` should use `app/main/catalog.php` etc.

my config looks like this

```
location ~* ^/admin {      
          alias $base_root/projectname/src/;
          try_files /app/main/index.php  =404;
                              
          fastcgi_pass   localhost:9010;
          fastcgi_read_timeout 20m;
                                                                                                 
          fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;                                           
          fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;        

          fastcgi_index  index.php;                                                      
                                                                      
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                                            
          fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
    }
```

Note: I need to use `alias` here, can't use `root`

This config works for `index.php` as intended: I open `localhost/admin`, I get `index.php` content

However I can't figure out configuration for other files

I tried using `try_files /app/main/$uri =404;`  but it only gives me 404 error on all pages

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, simply rewriting the URI should be sufficient:

```
rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /app/main/$1 last;

# your standard PHP handler location
location ~ \.php$ {
   # fastcgi configuration
   fastcgi_pass ...
}
```